# Need to make box relative to header HTML CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header and I need a small menu box below it, I'm trying to make sure I won't need to use `top` in css, and I can just add a line break in HTML. I have the following code for the header, the `global_tools_menu` is the menu I'm trying to add. For some reason, it starts from the top of the page? How would I make it start from just below the header? Here's the code
HTML:

```
<div class="global_header">
    <b><p>ex</p></b>
    <header>
        <ul class="nav-bar">
            <li class="nav-item global_tools" onclick="tools()"><a><img src="/ex/assets/tools.png" width="20px"/></a></li>
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                echo '<li class="nav-item right-3826" onclick="redirect(`myaccount`);"><a>My Account</a></li>';
                echo '<li class="nav-item right-3826" onclick="redirect(`scripts/logout.php`);"><a>Logout</a></li>';
            }
            if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                echo '<li class="nav-item right-3826" onclick="redirect(`login`);"><a>Log in</a></li>';
                echo '<li class="nav-item right-3826" onclick="redirect(`signup`)";><a>Sign Up</a></li>';
            }
            ?>
            <li class="nav-item" onclick="redirect('');"><a>Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" onclick="redirect('all');"><a>All</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" onclick="redirect('search');"><a>Search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div><br>
<div id="global_tools_menu">
    <div id="global_tools_true">

    </div>
    <div id="global_tools_false">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tools {
    background-image: url('assets/tools.png');
}
a {
    color: #009AFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body {
    font-family: 'PT-Sans', sans-serif;
}
.nav-bar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #009AFF;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.nav-item {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    width: calc(2px + 13%);
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #0050FF;
}
.nav-item a {
    color: white;
}
.nav-item:hover {
    background-color: #0039B5;
}
.right-3826 {
    float: right;
    border-right: 0px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.global_header p {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: -20px;
    color: white;
}
.global_header {
    background-color: #009AFF;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.global_tools {
    background-color: white; 
}
.global_tools:hover {
    background-color: #EAEAEA; 
}
#global_tools_menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #080808;
```

Here is a JSFiddle for that. I need to make that black box start from below the header?
https://jsfiddle.net/qypm88dm/

Comment: do you need `position: absolute;` on `.global_header`? https://jsfiddle.net/qypm88dm/1/

Comment: @Michael Coker I do, otherwise the header part gets messed up.

Comment: I need a way to make global_tools_menu relative but not have it affect the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the answer you were looking for but I would do this,

add

```
<div class="blank"></div>
```

just below

```
<div class="global_header">
...
</div>
```

so it would be

```
<div class="global_header">
...
</div>
<div class="blank"></div>
```

and css would be

```
.blank {
    height: 190px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qypm88dm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of `global_tools_menu` to `inline` instead of `absolute` or `relative` because those are in reference to the top left of the page, which is why it is up at the top. If you set it to inline it will pop down right below your header.

Edit: My mistake, that will set it behind it, but if you do that and then give it `margin-top: 200px` that will get it below it. But that may not be the exact fix you want.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I can do a little more playing with it and see what else I get.. sorry mate.